# Unmanaged memory is only freed up by force GC, but why?

Tags: .net, wpf, memory, garbage-collection, unmanaged-memory

We have a complex internal GUI application written in WPF. Sometimes we find the native memory is not freed up until we force `GC.Collect()`. Here's the statistics we collect on production environment.

[image]

We can see that there're spikes on unmanaged memory, but the managed memory usage stays lows and steady.

I know GC will occurred only when required, but the user does feel slow when there're huge amount of unclaimed unmanaged. It's obviously faster when we collect GC manually. The unmanaged memory could be freed up after GC, so I don't think it's a memory leak.

I also would like to have some experiences about how to identify what happens in the process. We have logs, and have collected several different logs with the same issue from multiple users. Unfortunately We failed to locate the similarity from different logs (look like it will happen and start happening in any time).

We cannot reproduce the issue in DEV or QA environment either, or I could try to use DebugDiag to trace the unmanaged allocation from different modules. BTW, there's no administrator privilege, so I cannot trace unmanaged allocation or setting up global flags in production environment.

But we can do full memory dump - does it help to identify the issue (and how)?

Comment: Is your application using lot of bitmaps? WPF caches bitmaps, references of unmanaged bitmaps inside managed object live as long as managed bitmap is disposed. If it isn't disposed automatically, it will be disposed in `GC.Collect()`

Comment: We don't explicitly use Bitmap. Is there anyway to check if it's used by referenced dlls?

Comment: ask here. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?forum=wpf      You have really interesting question.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: @Dudeman3000 what I can tell is it's because the runtime thinks it's not necessary to release the unmanaged memory to the OS for performance reason (next managed allocation doesn't need to request again). The hard part is to convince the client unmanaged memory usage is not necessarily a bad thing, and in the end I have to force GC when the managed/virtual memory ratio is too low so number would look prettier.

Comment: @JeffreyZhao So... When  we see thatmemory grow to some threshold (might be 4gb for the app) performance is significantly affected. We'd like to have this program run 24 / 7 but right now this memory leak prevents that, the application needs to be periodically restarted. It's either bc MapInfo Pro APIs are leaking memory, or because we are leaking memory, possibly due to array fragmentation / LOH (large object heap) fragmentation. I think the next step is to get some stats from a better ($) memory profiler, but the answer to this question would help me out: if there is a managed memory leak,

Comment: If there is a managed memory leak, does the VS memory profiler show that as used unmanaged memory?

Comment: @AkashKava I wouldn't expect the GC to deal with unmanaged memory. Does `GC.Collect()` work any different in that regard compared to the regular and automatic GC Collection?